# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы бот работал только по кнопкам? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, клавиатура

На php это можно, вроде как, сделать... Но можно ли на python? Тип, есть кнопка 'test', если на не нажать, отправится слово - 'Успешно', но если просто написать 'test', чтобы игнорировал

Comment: Можно вопрос? А какая вам разница, нажмет ли пользователь на кнопку или же напишет то же самое сообщением? Как думаете если вас поставить перед выбором, вы бы печатали вручную?

Comment: У кнопок клавиатуры есть необязательный параметр `payload`, почитайте про него.